# Spring Rabbit MQ listener issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My Configuration Class is below:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class NeuwMessagingConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
    return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public Queue myQueue() {
    return new Queue("event", true);
}


@Bean
public DirectExchange directExchange(){
    DirectExchange directExchange = new DirectExchange("neuw.direct.exchange",true,false);
    return directExchange;
}


@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    Binding binding = BindingBuilder
            .bind(new Queue("event"))
            .to(directExchange()).with("type");
    return binding;
}

@Bean()
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory(){
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    /*DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);*/
    return messageConverter;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}


@Bean
public MappingJackson2MessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2Converter());
    return factory;
}


@Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
}
}
```

The DTO is :-

```
public class TestDto {

private String message;
private int code;

@JsonProperty(value = "co-relation-id")
private String coRelationID;

public TestDto(String message, int code) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.coRelationID = uuid.toString();
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getCoRelationID() {
    return coRelationID;
}

public void setCoRelationID(String coRelationID) {
    this.coRelationID = coRelationID;
}
}
```

The Snippet for publishing the message is:-

```
TestDto testDto = new TestDto("test",200);

rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("neuw.direct.exchange","type", testDto);
```

And the snippet to listen the message is:-

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@RabbitListener(queues = "event", containerFactory = "listenerFactory")
public void Test(Message<TestDto> testDto){
    logger.info("TEST info "+testDto.getPayload().getCoRelationID());
    logger.error("TEST error "+testDto.getPayload().getCoRelationID());
    logger.warn("TEST warn "+testDto.getPayload().getCoRelationID());
    logger.debug("TEST debug "+testDto.getPayload().getCoRelationID());
    logger.trace("TEST trace "+testDto.getPayload().getCoRelationID());
}
```

The issue is the logs here are not coming up

but if I try with The snippet below then it works:-

```
public void Test(Object testDto){
   logger.info("TEST info");
   logger.error("TEST error");
   logger.warn("TEST warn");
   logger.debug("TEST debug");
   logger.trace("TEST trace");
}
```

it does goes to the logs but how to get the TestDto in that case? If I am doing something wrong in the configuration or not using the listner correctly? Need some resolution on this issue

Comment: You are sending the message with routing key "type" and the queue is defined as "event".

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski what should I do then?

Comment: Try changing "type" to "event" in your code responsible for publishing.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski that is the routing key only, to route to event queue

Comment: that won't publis to queue at all

Comment: With direct exchange routing key is the queue name. Does your old code publish the message to a queue? Have you verified that by checking the rabbit mq admin interface for example?

Comment: params are - exchange, route key, message

Comment: yeah it publishes

Comment: only thing is the argument type Object triggers the block listener method

Comment: And what is the queue name that has this message? Can you attach a screenshot of the rabbit admin to the question please?

Comment: but class directly or Message<TestDto> doesnot trggers the block

Comment: neuw.direct.exchange - exchange
event - queue
type - route key

Comment: How does it work if you have signature like this: `Test(TestDto testDto)`? No message wrapping but expected payload type

Comment: That doesn’t work either. Tried that too

Comment: @ArtemBilan it is not working with TestDto

Comment: Have a look at this section of docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#json-message-converter. Also I believe you should be getting some exceptions as well, are you getting any?

Comment: No exceptions. Even am looking out ways to debug. Not getting exceptions. The message gets pulled but not going to method block

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski I am getting the __TypeId__ header equal to the class name with full package in the queue in the message while publishing. Can that be a concern?

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski

Found the issue answered below. Very silly but very useful

Comment: Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with issue with the constructor of the POJO class - no default constructor, now the resolution was either to have a default one or have a constructor with @JsonCreator

Example:-

```
@JsonCreator
public TestDto(@JsonProperty("message") String message,
               @JsonProperty("code") int code,
               @JsonProperty(value = "co-relation-id") String coRelationID) {
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
        this.coRelationID = coRelationID;
}
```